# What is the difference between Dakshina Kali and Guhya Kali?

Tags: tantra, kali

[image]

What is the difference between Dakshina Kali and Guhya Kali as per the Tantric Scriptures? Did Goddess Kali assume the Guhya Kali form to slay any demon?

One image of Guhya-Kali from one famous temple of Bengal consecrated by Maharaj Nandakumar is enclosed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 9 forms of Kaali
1) Dakshin Kaali
2) Bhadra Kaali
3) Guhya Kaali
4) Kaamakalaa Kaali
5) Kaala Kaali
6) Shmashaan Kaali
7) Siddhi Kaali
8) Chanda Kaali
9) Dhana Kaali

All of these forms are explained in the Mahaakaala Samhitaa which is supposed to be 50.000 verses and has khandas for each of the above. However, sadly, only 2 khandas Guhya kaali khanda and kaamakalaa kaali khanda are available at present (and a part of kaala kaali khanda). All this is readily available and given below in a link form.

1) [Guhya kaali 1](https://archive.org/details/MahakalaSamhitaGuhyaKaliKhandaPartIDr.KishorNathJha_201710)

2) [Guhya kaali 2](https://archive.org/details/MahakalaSamhitaGuhyaKaliKhandaPartIIDr.KishorNathJha_201710)

3) [Guhya kaali 3](https://archive.org/details/MahakalaSamhitaPartIIIDr.KishorNathJha_201710)

4) [Kaamakalaa kaali](https://archive.org/details/MahakalaSamhitaUttaraKhandaKamaKalaKhandaDr.KishoriNathJha_201709)

There is a Ravana krit stotra of Kaamakalaa Kaali included in the Kaamakalaa khanda which is from 'Hiranyapur vijaya' of 'Vaamakeshwar Tantra'. (Regular copies of the Vaamakeshvara Tantra do not have it).All the above amount to only 7 to 8 thousand verses.
There is also a siddhi vetal sahasranaam stotra presumably from the Siddhi kaali khanda which is available at Asa Saphu archives.
Dakshin Kaali is readily available everywhere. In fact most of the literature referred to as Kaali is Dakshin Kaali.
In the Atharvana Samhitaa of the Haharava tantra additional worship of Guhya Kaali is specified. It is interesting to note that in Haharava Tantra the begining of a chapter is generally 'Sumeru prishtha sthite' as against the regular 'Kailaasa shikhare ramye'. Scholars would like to check whether this is relating to the Sumarian civilization.
As I am new here, I do not know whether this would qualify as an answer. My only aim is to provide as many links possible for research and knowledge.

Kalau Kaali Kalau Kaali Kalau Kaali tu siddhidaa |
Kalau Kaali Kalau Kaali Kalau Kaali tu kevalaa ||

Comment: No. It is Haahaaraava Tantra. Contains a Guhya Kaali sahasranaama as well as Kavach of kaali by kaalabhairav

Comment: Oh! I see! Haa-Haa-rava-Tantra. Thanks:)