# Forms of Kalika

Tags: tantra, kali

Is Samshana kali mentioned in Jayadrathayamala tantra? I've heard that Siddhilakshmi is flanked by Samshana kali and Raktakali. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey girlie I had to delete my first profile on here (cause I accidentally linked it to my FB account, embarrassing) but anyways from that profile I posted asking about Smashan Kali, and ChamundaDas typed an answer, here it is : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52075/could-someone-perhaps-direct-me-to-info-regarding-smashan-kali-guhya-kali Hopefully CD or one of the other Shakta guys on here sees this question you posted and gives a reply later :D

Comment: Thank u so much. I happen to know about her presence in Mahakala Samhita. What I was curious about is is she present in Jayadrathayamala. Anyway, very grateful for your interaction.